# Pointer to a script in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a gameObject and I want to get a value from one of the scripts. How would I point to the script? At the moment I am calling the gameObject from a script named Body and I want to get the script named RightArm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Body script you can do this, assuming that the Arm is inside the Body.

```
RightArm rArm = GetComponentInChildren<RightArm>();
```

It will look through all the Children and find the correct component you want. You can use this to find all sorts of Components, such as Rigibodies.

Assuming the RightArm is somewhere else, maybe on the floor outside the body. Then you can do this:

```
RightArm rArm = GameObject.Find("RightArm").GetComponent<RightArm>();
```

Let "RightArm" be the name of the GameObject containing the RightArm Script.

This second implementation will look through in the scene for the GameObject named "RightArm" then look at the components in that gameObject and return you the RightArm script. If there is no gameObject named "RightArm" then you will get an exception when trying to get a component of null.